# Is understanding the Quran better than memorizing it?

Tags: quran

Assalamualaikum my Brothers and Sisters,

A person can memorize 10 verses from the Quran (in Arabic) without understanding, or a person can actually learn and understand those same 10 verses. Which will give more good deeds?

Why I am asking this, is that Dr. Zakir Naik said that actually understanding 
Quranic verses is far, far better than simply reciting it. Do people get more good deeds by understanding the verses of Quran without memorizing them (in Arabic) or by memorizing them (in Arabic) without understanding?

Answer (score 1):

walaikum asalam,
if i talk my about my personal views then i think understanding Qur'an is far better.
this is just because when you understand qur'an, the first reward is that you will deeply understand islam and the second is interest. after understanding Qur'an, you can recite Qur'an with great interest, you can talk about a problem linking it with some versus of Qur'an and hadith while on the other hand, you may memorize Qur'an but you can't tell someone about a problem in light of Qur'an.
some peoples' concern is that islam has defined great rewards for memorizing Qur'an, if you are confused by this than how can you reward someone by understanding his mother language(Arabic at that time). 
understand Qur'an. Understand Islam.

Comment: Or i can memorise and along with memorising i do understand Quran .. i think that is good option

Comment: memorizing with understanding is best option.

Comment: Now my target is inshallah 1st i will memorize 1st whole para and then i do memorize it’s meaning

Comment: but i will suggest you to memorize its meaning first, this could be helpful while memorizing para as you will understand the meaning. try understanding basics of arabic grammar can help you greatly